# graphics.IsFullScreen resetting to false after game constructor and graphics.ApplyChanges()

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, graphics, monogame

This is a MonoGame 3.2 Windows (DirectX) Project.

I've tried setting `graphics.IsFullScreen` to true in the game's constructor and in the game's initialize function, both times running `graphics.ApplyChanges()`, but when stepping through the code, I see that it gets set back to false when it leaves the constructor or `graphics.ApplyChanges()` is called. Here is the code I've tried:

```
public class Sandbox : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public Sandbox()
        : base()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        IsFixedTimeStep = false;
        IsMouseVisible = true;

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = Config.Screen.Width;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = Config.Screen.Height;

        graphics.IsFullScreen = Config.Screen.IsFullScreen; // IsFullScreen reads true
        graphics.ApplyChanges(); // IsFullScreen reads true
    } // IsFullScreen reads FALSE when leaving the constructor

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        graphics.IsFullScreen = true; // IsFullScreen reads true
        graphics.ApplyChanges(); // IsFullScreen reads FALSE after applying changes

        graphics.ToggleFullScreen(); // this did not do anything

        base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the actual width and height you're trying to set here?

Comment: @JoshPetrie I've tried multiple, including my native resolution.

Comment: I think this might be a known issue.. have a look at the issues list on github https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/2758

Comment: Or this one https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/1672